# Volume Shadow Copy Service and the Local Settings folder(s)

Tags: windows-server-2008, vss, windows-xp

Environment:

- Server: Windows Server 2008
- Client computers: Windows XP Pro SP 3

I discovered that the "Local Settings" folder in a user's profile's directory does not exist when I open up the profile's folder using Previous Verions. I already tried showing all hidden files.

Any suggestions for allowing VSS to periodically back up the folder will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are on the clients (thus "Local").  You can't back them up from the server.

I'm not a hardcore Windows Admin, YMMV.

Comment: To elaborate, it turns out that the IT administrator had only set up the Desktop and My Documents folders to live on the server. This misconception that "Local Settings" can only live on the local computer may explain his mistake. Unfortunately, since I have a low accept rate, I've accepted this answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help by misconceiving.